# Convert Column to Row in Scala

Tags: scala, pandas, pyspark, transpose

I am looking for solution to convert row to column in Scala. After hours of findings, I still cannot figure this out. Look at the example below for input and my expected output.

Input:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|   A    |    B   |    C   |
+--------+--------+--------+
|   10   |   15   |    6   |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------+
|   A    |   10   |
+--------+--------+
|   B    |   15   |
+--------+--------+
|   C    |    6   |
+--------+--------+
```

Comment: How does work `df.T` or `df.transpose()` ?

Answer (score 0):

if the number of rows (lists) is arbitrary, you can follow this pattern:

```
for { (e1, e2) <- (list1 zip list2) } yield List(e1, e2)
```

otherwise maybe something like this:

```
def rows2cols[T](rows: List[List[T]]) = {
  //assuming equal length skipping checks for emptiness:
  for (el <- 0 until rows.head.length) yield {
    rows.map(_(el))
  }
}

rows2cols(List(
  List(1,2,3),
  List(4,5,6)
))

//Vector(List(1, 4), List(2, 5), List(3, 6))
```

of course code above is very simplified and missing all necessary checks for length, emptiness etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List.transpose` in scala.

```
val xs = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6)).transpose
xs: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 4), List(2, 5), List(3, 6))
```